# Meteor App Fails To Load Due To Errors

Tags: debugging, meteor

I'm just trying/learning Meteor by reading the *Discover Meteor* book, and everything is great.

But, sometimes I made some mistake at the code, ran the meteor app, and no error was written at console. If I visit the `localhost:3000`, I just see a blank document with the name of the app written on it.

So it is clear that something went wrong during the app loading, but I don't know where or what, so I have to review all the files.

I can't accept that some guys developed this amazing framework haven't placed, somewhere, a log file with errors. So I'm assuming that the problem is that I haven't found it yet.

So... where are the rendering errors outputed?

Note: sometimes, I have seen errors at console, for example when a variable was not declared. But often, 0 error messages show up, and the blank page appears.

Comment: There are two consoles, one is the server side one. If you get a blank page you've likely made a javascript error on the client side on the Developer Tools window. Do you check both for errors?

Comment: Nothing at the server console, and just the GET request and answer due to the page load appear at the browser console.

Comment: I mean have you checked for Javascript errors on the browser console as well? This is the most likely place to have errors if you have a blank page. It won't show the GET request/answer in that area. Check the console tab instead of the network tab if you're using chrome under the Developer Tools window

Comment: I'm using Firefox&Firebug, I am at the Console tab, and when showing "All", the GET request is shown. It is the only item shown. If i go to "Errors" tab, nothing appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no errors in both consoles, I think this is not a code error but a logic one. Check your application variables by using the browser console, check if your template named correctly and check if your router works the way you need.

Comment: Sure, in fact I did found the error. The problem is, I may not find it easily the next time, so Meteor should give us some hints when something is not ok. I can't believe this is not a feature, so that's why I'm asking for it, since I might have missed that feature

Comment: Just for future reference, could you share what the problem was?

Comment: @SandervandenAkker Forgot to suscribe to a publication, but anyway is not applicable to the question, since yesterday had the same problem due to a different error. What I am asking for is for some kind of log with interpretation errors on initialization. Does that even exist?